# XSLT – adding number attribute relative to an ancestor

Tags: xslt

I would like to retrieve a copy of my original xml document with an added number attribute for each of the nodes, that would be counted not in relation to the parent node, but to an ancestor. Transforming, for instance:

```
<collection>
   <poem>
     <head>THE RAVEN.</head>
     <stanza>
      <l>ONCE upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,</l>
      <l>Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore,</l>
      <l>While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,</l>
      <l>As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door.</l>
      <l>“ ‘Tis some visiter,” I muttered, “tapping at my chamber door —</l>
      <l>Only this, and nothing more.”</l>
    </stanza>
    <stanza>
      <l>Ah, distinctly I remember it was in the bleak December,</l>
      <l>And each separate dying ember wrought its ghost upon the floor.</l>
      ...
    </stanza>
   </poem>
   <poem>
     ...
   </poem>
</collection>
```

into:

```
 <collection>
   <poem>
     <head>THE RAVEN.</head>
     <stanza n="1">
      <l n="1">ONCE upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,</l>
      <l n="2">Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore,</l>
      <l n="3">While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,</l>
      <l n="4">As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door.</l>
      <l n="5">“ ‘Tis some visiter,” I muttered, “tapping at my chamber door —</l>
      <l n="6">Only this, and nothing more.”</l>
    </stanza>
    <stanza n="2">
      <l n="7">Ah, distinctly I remember it was in the bleak December,</l>
      <l n="8">And each separate dying ember wrought its ghost upon the floor.</l>
      ...
    </stanza>
   </poem>
   <poem>
     ...
   </poem>
</collection>
```

I.e. counting each line from the poem ancestor rather than the stanza.

I don't seem to manage to use the xsl:number function properly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "*would be counted not in relation to the parent node, but to an ancestor.*" Which ancestor? Your example is ambiguous: it could be counting from `poem` or from `collection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to restart the count for each `poem`, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="stanza | l">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="n">
            <xsl:number from="poem" level="any"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Remove the `from` attribute to get a consecutive count throughout the entire document.